# Call functions on an instantiated C++ class returned by a PInvoke to a C function

Tags: c#, c++-cli, pinvoke

I have an unmanaged DLL that exports C style non-member functions for creating (say CreateObject) and destroying objects (DestroyObject). CreateObject returns a C++ class as a void*, which in the unmanaged code is cast to a known interface (defined only in a header file) and worked with. Is there a way to call methods on the IntPtr that is returned to me by CreateObject?

Dumpbin /EXPORT doesn't show me any methods of the C++ class, just the exported C functions (mentioned above).

*I would like to avoid having to write C++ CLI code or a purely unmanaged DLL that simply exposes methods on this class as function wrappers if possible*

This is Windows/MSVC only, so answers that restrict compatibility to Windows/MSVC are fine.

**NOTE: I'm talking about invoking C++ methods on a void*/IntPtr returned by a C function - not P/Invoking the C functions.**

Thanks!

Comment: This is a pretty common way a C++ programmer would expose his class as a C interface.  CreateObject() calls the constructor and returns the object pointer, to be treated as a "handle".  DestroyObject() calls the destructor.  And there will be more functions that take the "handle" as the first argument.  Very easy to pinvoke, the "handle" is just IntPtr.  Hard to guess what you are fretting about.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm "fretting" about the fact that you didn't grok the question. CreateObject returns void* that needs to be cast to a C++ class and methods on it need invoking for use - I'm talking about invoking methods on this void*/IntPtr. I can VERY EASILY PInvoke CreateObject and DestroyObject and have already done so. Thanks!

Comment: Why the downvote? I haven't seen any question on SO dealing with this topic. So even if the answer is you HAVE to use a C++ (or C++/CLI) bridge - it's still a valid question conforming to all the SO etiquettes

Comment: Is there a particular reason to not write a native/managed bridge library?  Not that I can't think of a couple, but just interested in your reason.

Comment: I actually have - but my main reason to not do this is that I have to lug around one native DLL for each architecture instead of a single nice, AnyCPU dll that works on ALL supported architectures. It's also for the sake of learning any techniques that I might not know.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ruling out C++/CLI, and only have an `IntPtr` containing the address of the instance then you have few options remaining.

As I see it you are left with p/invoke. In order to call a method you'll need to export it from your unmanaged code. You'll also need to be careful about the calling convention. Commonly it will be `__thiscall`. When you write the p/invoke, you must explicitly add the `this` pointer as the first parameter.

This is fine so far as it goes. But you'll not be able to export virtual methods this way. You cannot call them using p/invoke.

Frankly though the cleanest and simplest way to do this interop is with our old friend, tried and tested COM. This very scenario is just what it was designed for. C++ classes are not designed for interop across compiler/language boundaries. That's what COM is for.

Comment: Note that I haven't written the C DLL with this mixed-paradigm interface and therefore don't have any control over what it gives  me. All I want to do is consume it in the least painful way possible. I am currently using a fully unmanaged DLL that exports each function in that interface with a C wrapper - but want to see if there's any way to avoid this.

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify - The original DLL has no C++ exports (the C++ bits are header only - the interface I need to cast that void* to), which is why I referred to that as a C DLL. Also, I exported C functions of the form Func1(void* ptr, OtherParam otherParam) from an unmanaged DLL for all functions in the interface and P/Invoke to these functions, passing in the void* (IntPtr) given to me by CreateObject. Internally, these functions cast and invoke functions on that header-only interface - so I called them C wrappers. Hope that makes things clearer.